# How do to check and uncheck other checkbox in a loop one at same time?

Tags: javascript, python, for-loop, selenium-chromedriver

I have three checkboxes with the ids

```
id = ["inputListings_I","inputListings_A","inputListings_B"]
```

My question: using a loop, I want to check one checkbox at at time and unselect the other. Suppose I select id[0] and then loop select id[1] but it should uncheck id[0], if loop select id[2] it should uncheck id[1].

How to do that?

```
lst = ["inputListings_I","inputListings_A","inputListings_B"]

for i in lst:
    mm = driver.find_element_by_id(i)
    if (mm.is_selected()):
        js = f"document.getElementById({i}).click()"
        driver.execute_script(js)
    js = f"document.getElementById('{i}').click()"
    driver.execute_script(js)"
    """unselect other two"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than toggling them willy-nilly, just set the `checked` property:

```
lst = ["inputListings_I","inputListings_A","inputListings_B"]

choice = "inputListings_A"
for i in lst:
    js = f"document.getElementById({i}.checked = {i == choice}"
    driver.execute_script(js)
```